# Android Framework sych for an particular app with work manager

Tags: android, synchronization, account, android-workmanager

In Android I am trying framework sync in setting--account and synch option.How to work with work manager anyone give suggestions and link for this.Now in devlopers site instead of sych adapter how to use work manager for this account please suggest

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, clarify what specific problem you're trying to solve and what difficulties have prevented you from solving it yourself? I also recommend to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask so that your question could find the answer

Comment: please your question is not specific, make more detail your question and experiments has been done